# Is there any way I can increase my home folder size without uninstalling again?  

Tags: installation, partitioning

This is my problem, I downloaded the ubuntu 11.10 ISO file from the web.
I burned it on a CD, inserted the CD, shutdown the computer, installed Ubuntu 11.10 and there was a moment I was asked how much space I wanted to dedicate to it, it was default 18GB and I left it that way. Unfortunately, I didn't really know what I was doing and now my homefolder is only 18GB big with only 2.4 GB free.
I do not have a partition for my home folder, this is how it looks like

[My partitions](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/9089/printlm.png)

Is there any way I can increase my home folder size WITHOUT uninstalling ubuntu again?

Comment: Your image file indicates an 181GB partition for Ubuntu. I don't see a separate partition for a /home folder. It looks like you have plenty of room, 175GB if I'm not mistaken. I'm only fluent in English so I may have miss read the labels in your image.

Comment: @fragos: note that the partition you're referring to is not mounted, and the first ntfs partition is mounted at /host. I have a feeling this is a Wubi install

Comment: you see everything right, there is indeed 175GiB free, but my homefolder has only 2.2 GiB free...
I also saw this post, but that couldn't really help me

http://askubuntu.com/questions/18462/expanding-your-home-directory-size

Answer (score 1):

You can resize a partition by booting from the Ubuntu Live CD. There's a chance you might have some data loss when resizing partitions with data on them, but if it's a fresh install what's to loose? I've used this method to successfully resize a partition with Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual booted HD. If you're Ubuntu install didn't come with gparted, just open software center from the live CD and install it. You can then un-mount the drive to be resized if it's mounted, then select it with gparted and choose resize.

Comment: when i insert my cd i can only choose between try and install ubuntu

Comment: yes indeed people it was a wubi install and It looked like this
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Wubi_screenshot.png

Comment: Select try Ubuntu. You can use gParted from the live cd after selecting try Ubuntu.

Comment: I am now on try ubuntu but there is nothing that indicates my home folder

Comment: You'll see the home folder in `/media/yourdrivehere` (it will have a long name like this: `fd306a7e-4074-45c2-b29c-f9b540077949`. You don't need to access the home folder to resize the partition though. You only need to open gparted and locate the partition containing your new installation.