# Increase size of / and /home

Tags: partitioning

Hi I have a 20 GB partition for `/` and 14 GB for `/home`. I want to shrink C:/ to 20 GB and add each 10 GB to `/` and `/home`. But I cannot do this as if I shrink C drive, the unallocated 20 GB is cannot be added to either `/` or `/home`. For more info I am telling that 4 drives are extended partition and the rest is primary. So how to extend this partition?

Screenshot of Windows 7 Disk Management - http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5977/snap1sv.jpg

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you want / to be 30Gb? Seems rather large. I'd agree with the use of gparted from live environments - but I would be inclined to use the windows disk too to do the initial shrink of the windows partition.

Comment: just want it to be 30 GB in case if ever I have low on /.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way I can increase my home folder size without uninstalling again?  ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110060/is-there-any-way-i-can-increase-my-home-folder-size-without-uninstalling-again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this many times and the best way is to either boot Ubuntu from live CD or from HDD.

then make sure everything needed is install.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted ntfsprogs
```

[image]
Open Gparted , make sure `C:` is unmounted.

click and select resize , then apply.

after doing this you will need to be on a Live CD.

to resize your `/ & /home` partitions

Comment: Your Unity UI looks good. What icons and theme you r using? Link please..

Comment: Icons http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=133366  Theme http://grvrulz.deviantart.com/art/Hope-gtk3-206207315

Answer (score 1):

Boot from Ubuntu LiveCD and use GParted to resize your `C:` partition, then move the `C:` partition farther by 10Gb - this will create a 10Gb hole after your / partition. Resize your / partition to use that space.

Then move the origin of the extended partition to use the unallocated 10Gb after the C: partition, and move the logical partitions inside the extended partition one by one so the empty space is at the end of the extended partition. Resize the extended partition shrinking its size by 10 Gb.

Then resize the `/home` partition.

TL;DR: Boot from Ubuntu LiveCD; move partitions one by one. :) (also I'm not sure I correctly understood which partition is which)

As jippie pointed out, make sure you have backups!

Also, moving the origin of any bootable partitions will require re-configuring the boot-loader, GParted warns about this and gives an URL to a page with detailed instructions

Comment: GParted has a good track record, but be sure to make backups of your files!

Comment: @jippie: good point!

Comment: Doing this, Will lead to a reinstallation of Windows?

Comment: I think No, but it will be better backup your C:/ in case of system failure.