# Does resizing / and /home keep the system as previous?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, home-directory

Referring from this question: [increase-size-of-and-home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122199/increase-size-of-and-home), I want to know that if i follow the process in the solution will it affect my system? Currently my system looks like this,
[image: GParted screenshot]

I want only to increase the size of `/home`. it could be form `sda3` or from `/`. Now If i follow the steps in the answer will it delete my files? Can i take space from `/dev/sda3` and allocate it to `/home`? or from the `/`? Which will be better? Or I just created a folder `/home` in `/` and link it to `/home` directory. Please suggest.

Comment: First of all you can't re-size partitions if they are not contiguous. Partitions can be extended with unallocated contiguous disk area. Your second option 'home link' is logical and easy. you should go for that in my opinion..

Comment: yes. i was thinking of taking some space from `/` in my first option. the `sda3` is only a possibility. thank you for your suggestion. You may elaborate your opinion and put it in answer.